# Android: Leaked intenreceiver, trying to keep receiver alive in background

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a service that runs in the background, a PacketListener. The listener sends broadcasts which intent receiver in other classes receive.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("UPDATE_LIST"));
```

I have an intent receiver in my Main.class that I want to keep alive, even when the user presses the Home button and the app goes in the background. So in my onPause() in Main class I'm not unRegistering the receiver on purpose. However I'm getting an Exception in LogCat that says "Main has leaked IntentReceiver, unregisterReceiver()?"

```
@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    if (dataUpdateReceiver == null) 
    {
        dataUpdateReceiver = new DataUpdateReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("UPDATE_LIST");        
        registerReceiver(dataUpdateReceiver, intentFilter);
    }


    if (imReceiver == null)
    {
        imReceiver = new IMReceiver();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("IM");
        registerReceiver(imReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    super.onResume();       
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to keep intent receivers alive without leaking?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to register Your `Receiver` in the `Manifest` file.For manifest registration if your app is not running, a new process will be created to handle the broadcast. If you register it in code, it's tied to the life of the activity/service you registered it in.

Sample code for registering receiver in manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".ReceiverDemo">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="marakana.intent.action.ReceiverDemo" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Do like this for registering your receiver class

```
<receiver android:name="receiver class name with package" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="your intent action" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```